# New 27" monitor seems grainy

Tags: display, resolution

I have just bought a new monitor -
Acer G277HLBID 27 Inch HDMI IPS LED Monitor.

It seems to be grainy and dark, I have tried HDMI and DVI but i get the same result with both. Also the same with my PC and PS4.

Any one know a solution?

Comment: What's the resolution of the monitor?

Comment: The OP said HDMI, and from Acer's website, it says 1920x1080.  I suppose he could be running it at a lower resolution ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are not satisfied with your purchase.  The first thing to do is to work out whether the unit you have is faulty, or if it is just how that model line is, or even the product category (all 27 HDMI monitors)?  Have you seen this monitor working either at work, a friends, or in a showroom?  Have seen any 27 inch monitors that you like?

I personally think that HDMI (1080p / 1920 x 1080) resolution is too low for 27 inch and larger monitors, so I'm going to get a 3K monitor later this year, but I have to upgrade my laptop to support that resolution as well.

If you bought it from a good retailer, then I would just return it.